# I always get stuck here... Divs not behaving properly (alignment issues)

Tags: css, html

I don't know why, after encountering this problem dozens of times, the answer always seems different and I can't seem to work my way through the problem-solving process, but here I am again with misaligned divs.

I've got 3rows encasing columns. each row is to have (at least) 3 columns (and probably some nested divs down the line, but I'm not even there yet). I'm trying to make a fluid chunk in the center ultimately, with pretty corners. However, my top row is already showing signs of misbehaving.  >.O

Please help with my silly questions!

Cheers and thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">

#wrap {
    margin:auto;
    width:80%;
    height:75%;
    border: solid #066 1px;}

#row1 {
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background:#F20;
    }
    #r1c1 {
        float:left; 
        width:05%;}
    #r1c2 {
        float:left; 
        width:80%}
    #r1c3 {
        clear:both;
        width:05%;
        }


#row2 {
    float:none;
    width:100%;
    background:#0C6;
    }   
#r2c1 {}
#r2c2 {}
#r2c3 {}



#row3   {
    width:100%;
    height:15%;
    background:#00F;
    clear:both;
    }
#r3c1 {}
#r3c2 {}
#r3c3 {}



</style>

<body>

<div id="wrap">
<div id="row1"> 
    <div id="r1c1">LEFT</div>
    <div id="r1c2">CENT</div>
    <div id="r1c3">RIGHT</div>
    </div>

<div id="row2"> 
MIDDLE
    </div>

<div id="row3"> 
BOTTOM
    </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post on DocType pls... see faq!

Comment: row 1 column 3 should be float: none or float: left, not clearing. for the rest, tl;dr

Comment: @Simon: True, SO cannot be considered fully relevant for this question - http://www.doctype.com is more relevant.

Comment: what do you mean "fluid chunk"?

Comment: @Simon ? post on doctype?
-----------------------------------
@Andrew Bullock Fluid chunk--- like, fluid width/height and rounded corners...
-----------------------------------

@davidsomething:  I had r1c3 on float left, but then it was running into the others in the row and row2 was overlapping. I found a post on a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005301/why-are-divs-behaving-like-this   ... Doing that sorta solved some of the problems and created new ones >.<

Comment: oh!!! I thought, since I found so many css positioning questions here, that it was a good place to ask!
Sorry!

Comment: hope you can select an answer, Seems my solution is the same as the one you linked.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want this?

on r1c3 delete clear both, and use `float:right` instead,
or alternetively just add this at the end of your css, it will just overwrite the ones you currently have

```
#r1c3 { clear: none }
#row1 { overflow: hidden }
```